# Java socket keeps freezing

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I'm trying to implement a simple server(java application) and client(android app), where the client sends a string about 10 times a second. Everything works fine for a minute or so, after which the server stops receiving messages from the client. Relevant code below.

**ClientThread.java**

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable{
static Socket socket;
static String message = "";
InetAddress serverAddr;
BufferedOutputStream bos;

public ClientThread(String message){
    ClientThread.message = message;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
        if(socket != null && socket.isConnected())socket.close();
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream (socket.getOutputStream());
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(bos, "US-ASCII");
        osw.write(message);
        osw.flush();
        socket.shutdownOutput();
        socket.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
}
```

**ServerThread.java**

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread{
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    static String clientSentence;

   public ServerThread(int port) throws IOException, AWTException{
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
   }

   public void run() {
      while(true){
         try{
            Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
            clientSentence = d.readLine();
            System.out.println(clientSentence);
            server.close();
         }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

ClientThread.java is called about 10 times a second using:

```
Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ClientThread(message));
clientThread.start();
```

ServerThread.java is initialized and started using:

```
t = new ServerThread(8888);
t.start();
```

Any thoughts on why this would freeze after running for a bit? The only way to fix it is to restart the server, after which the same problem happens again after a minute. I spent a lot of time researching this issue but was unable to find a solution.

EDIT: I figured out the server freezes at the clientSentence = d.readLine(); part. Any idea why?

Comment: Be sure a clientthread is finished before you start a new one.

Comment: Better use only one thread and a permanent connected socket.

Comment: You always instantiate a new thread in a loop?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. Not in a loop but rather in a function that starts the clientThread 10 times a second.

Answer (score 1):

60 connection per second, one minute running: 3600 connections per minute.

[Closing a socket doesn't release **immediately** the associated file descriptor.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination) You may run out of resource at OS layer.

Try to run `netstat` on server side to see the active, pending and closed connections.

You may [read this post on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/173535/what-are-close-wait-and-time-wait-states).

Answer (score 0):

Your thread never exits and you keep creating new ones. So you run out of something: thread space, sockets, FDs, ...

This is all wrong. *Either* your thread should loop *or* you should create a new one. Not both.

Also:

1. You should use a single connection, not a new one per message.
2. You are reading lines but to sending them, unless the data already contains a newline, which it shouldn't.